# I cant find sound configuration option on sounds settings

Tags: 20.04, sound, bluetooth, a2dp

The sound configuration option is missing from where I want to change my configuration to A2DP, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

What I've already tried:

- Installed `pavucontrol`. But A2DP option was missing from there too.
- I've edited the `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` file:

  ```
  sudo -H gedit /etc/bluetooth/main.conf
  ```

  and added this line in the end of it:

  ```
  Disable=Headset
  ```

But, it didn't work for me.